# On click matching in jQuery via a data-id

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

```
 <div class="share-tooltip-wrapper" data-id="<?php echo $post_ID; ?>">
    <div class="share-tooltip">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <ul class="share-list">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode(CURRENT_URL); ?>" target="_blank" class="share-facebook">
                    <span class="icon">Facebook</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Hello - I'm making a wordpress site and a section of that site has "share button"(s) all with unique ids, that correspond to the shareable post. The problem is below with my jquery code, I'm trying to write code that will essentially say when you've clicked my share button with a data-id, then change the html of a node with that same data-id. so i can go from a share to shared state on the button. If I don't have some unique id, then all the elements on the page are changed.

```
var current = jQuery(this).filter("id");
 jQuery("ul").find("[data-id='" + current + "']").on("click", function(event){
        console.log("clicked");

        // jQuery('span.share-text').html('<span class="share-text">Shared</span>');
    });
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need to have unique id to avoid all of your elements on the page to changed. YOu can add click listener for a dom and traverse from there where you want to make change. This will make sure that you have change only in ur desired dom.

Comment: well i would do that if the element i wanted changed was a direct descendant of the button. The problem is that my tool-tip share button isn't a decedent of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
$(".share-facebook").click(function(){
  // $(this).parent("li").append($("<span>").html("shared").addClass("share-text"));
 // $(this).remove();
});​
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/NvWVh/24/

Comment: well no the one cavet is, the .share-facebook element has no parent, it is a tooltip item that is associated with the body and not a child of the particular item i'd like to change the status of. AKA if you click the .share-facebook button, then it will change all items on the page with a certain id. I need it to change only the node of the matching data-id number.

Comment: Could you see if you are looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/NvWVh/12/

Also I could clearly see in your posted code share-facebook do have parent dom.

Comment: I'd agree with you based on the code. Yet, I'm seeing it differently on my console. where it looks like this: html > body.js > div.share-tooltip > ul.share-list li > a.share-facebook

Comment: Could you put what is seen in you console or when you do page source. THat will help alot.

Comment: code <div class="component-share" data-url="http://www.dev/action/bss-test-survey/" data-name="BSS Test Survey" data-id="1">
    <a class="share-button">
        <span class="share-icon">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="share-text">Share</span>
    </a>
    <div class="share-tooltip-wrapper" data-id="1">
        <div class="share-tooltip">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <ul class="share-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.facebook..." target="_blank" class="share-facebook">
                        <span class="icon">Facebook</span> code

Comment: And you want to edit this DOM <div class="component-share" data-url="dev/action/bss-test-survey/"; data-name="BSS Test Survey" data-id="1">  ??? Or <div class="share-tooltip-wrapper" data-id="1">

Comment: text within the component-share class, but only the one with a matching data-id. Or else it will edit all DOM elements with that class.

Comment: Could you see this http://jsfiddle.net/NvWVh/24/ . If your HTML DOM matches with mine.

Comment: i get back undefined for this:     
        jQuery(".share-facebook").on("click", function(e) {
            var divComponent = jQuery(this).closest(".component-share");
            console.log(jQuery(divComponent).attr("data-id"));
            e.preventDefault();
        });

Comment: Can you cross check the DOM i had in jfiddle is same as you have. I am getting 1 for it.

Comment: THE ANSWER:  jQuery(".share-list a").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tooltip = jQuery(this).parents(".share-tooltip");
            var data_id = tooltip.attr("data-id");
            var share_button = jQuery(".component-share[data-id=" + data_id + "]");
            console.log(share_button);
        });

Answer (score 1):

The jquery method find searches child element of the element but you have to find parent of ul which has attribulte data-id so try using closest to search up the tree in parents.

```
 jQuery("ul").closest("[data-id='" + current + "']").on("click", function(event){
    console.log("clicked");

    // jQuery('span.share-text').html('<span class="share-text">Shared</span>');
 });
```

Comment: is this the best way to set current?        var current = jQuery(this).filter("id");

Comment: Depends on situation, could not find the statement in the OP

Comment: I guess my question really boils down to how do I get jQuery to save the data-id of the selected button in a variable. So I may then have a  way to know when a li that matches that data-id has also been clicked.

Comment: jQuery(".share-list a").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var tooltip = jQuery(this).parents(".share-tooltip");
            var data_id = tooltip.attr("data-id");
            var share_button = jQuery(".component-share[data-id=" + data_id + "]");
            console.log(share_button);
        });

Answer (score 0):

According to your html the data-id attribute is for the div.

And you seem to find it inside of ul.

Try to find the closest or the parent of the ul and then try.

```
jQuery("ul").closest("[data-id='" + current + "']").on("click", function(event){
    console.log("clicked");

});
```

Comment: true, but i still need to find a proper method to save my "current" variable so I know what the current id selected is. right?